# how display image from database in php

Tags: php, sql, image, pdo

I have a problem with displaying an image from the database. I don't know how to display it. The path of the image is saved in the database. The rest of the columns display correctly, but not the image.

```
<?php

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cars",'root','');

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $str = $_POST["search"];
    $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE name = '$str'");

    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
    $sth -> execute();

    if($row = $sth->fetch())
    {
        ?>
        <div class = "container-fluid">
        <div class = "panel panel-default">
        <div class = "panel-body">
        <table id = "table" class = "table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>photo</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->Brand; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Type; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Year; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->photo; ?></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
        else{
            echo "Car doesnt exist";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is HTML 101. Use [`<img src>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use _parameterised queries_ (just using prepared statements is not enough on its own!) to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / PDO. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Also, **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: it just for learn for myselft

Comment: In that case you should take note of what I've written, and learn good habits instead of bad ones! Then when you come to write some code for "real" use, you won't have to learn all over again.

Comment: As this is just a learning exercise, maybe you could add an example row from your database? As well as requiring an `<img src="path.to.file">` tag, you will want to make sure that the path to your image is actually correct!

Answer (score 3):

Do it with an img tag, also check the src of the image if it isn't showing the image.

```
<td><img src="<?php echo $row->photo; ?>" /></td>
```